# Backing up PostgreSQL Database in Linux

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have to create a postgresql database back up(only the schema) in Linux and restore it on a window machine. I backed up the database with option -E, but I was not able to restore it on the window machine.

Here is the command that I used to backup the database

```
pg_dump -s -E SQL_ASCII books > books.backup
```

below is the error message that I received when I tried to restore it.

```
C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin\pg_restore.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --dbname "books" --role "sa" --no-password  --list "C:\progress_db\test1"
pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.
```

Am I supposed to use a different command or am I missing something? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the error message? "input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql"

Comment: I did read the error message. It was the main reason why I used the option -E SQL_ASCII, so that it does not create a text format file.

Comment: `-E` sets the character encoding, it has nothing to do with the format. Look for  `-F`. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/app-pgdump.html Anyway, you 'd normally prefer to do the text dump.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's my understanding of the option E that is creating the confusion for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first lines in the official [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE) about restoring say:

> The text files created by pg_dump are intended to be read in by the
>   psql program. The general command form to restore a dump is
>
> psql dbname < infile
>
> where infile is the file output by the pg_dump command

Or simply read the error message.

The option `-E SQL_ASCII` only sets the character encoding, it has nothing to do with the format of the dump. By default, `pg_dump` generates a text file that contains the SQL statements to regenerate the database; in this case, to restore the database you only need to execute the sql commands in the file, as in a psql terminal - that's why a simple `psql dbname < mydump` is the way to go.

`pg_restore` is to be used with the alternative "binary" -postgresql specific- format of `pg_dump`.